# Array of images to store in cache?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-sharedpreferences

I am working with the `cards` ([cardView](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/cardview)) and trying to store the images inside the array (array to string; store that in cache and when required unpack back to array). My question is: what is the most convenient way to store the images in an array?

Store the bitmaps (bitmapToString etc)? Turn the bitmaps (I get the images from the gallery and camera) into URIs? Absolute paths?

The number of images is small (3-4), so, I guess, there's no need in a DB.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Android `Bitmap` objects are not good candidates for storing in Java arrays - they are very large objects so you run the risk of an `OutOfMemoryException`. It is easy to create a memory leak if you are not careful.

If you have to get some photos from the gallery as `Bitmap` and retain them in your app, one of the patterns that is normally used is writing the `Bitmap` to the app's internal storage (covered [here](https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/files).

If you need a reference to the stored photo, you can save the filename or a `Uri` that represents the photo or image.

Then the problem of loading `Bitmap`s etc. into an `ImageView` is solved with libraries like [Picasso](http://square.github.io/picasso/) or [Glide](https://github.com/bumptech/glide). You can use these to load from the local file system, or from online.